# want to calculate the average of marks but it won't print decimal points (java)

Tags: java

```
public class NotenDurchschnitt{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int note1, note2, note3;
        double schnitt;

        note1 = 3;
        note2 = 4;
        note3 = 6;

        schnitt = (note1 + note2 + note3) / 3;

        System.out.println("Notenschnitt ist: " + schnitt);

    }
}
```

first of all note = mark, schnitt = average (it's German) so basically I try to print out a number which is like that(this is why it's not like the other questions!!!):

```
1.0 / 1.5 / 2.0 / 2.5 / 3.0 / 3.5 / 4.0 / 4.5 / 5.0 / 5.5 / 6.0
```

6 is the best mark and 1 is the worst.

The thing is in my program it only would print 1.0, 2.0,...

Comment: The cause of the problem is the same. The part  "(note1 + note2 + note3) / 3" is an integer division just like in the other question. The same solution also applies: you need to make of your arguments a float or double before doing the division, so e.g."(note1 + note2 + note3) / 3.0" would work.

Answer (score 6):

You're doing *integer* division, which truncates decimals. Try this instead:

```
schnitt = (note1 + note2 + note3) / 3.0;
```

Comment: yes, otherwise Java thinks you want to do an integer division.

Comment: yeah but now I get 4.333.... how do I get .0 or .5?

Comment: @Robin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java

Comment: @vincrichaud can't find something like what I want there...

Comment: What do you mean? the code in the question is calculating `(3 + 4 + 6) / 3.0`, which is `4.333`, and that's correct. The question in the original post has been answered, if you have further questions please post them in a separate post

Comment: use Math.round() for rounding off decimals... otherwise 4.333 is correct